# Javascript regex to match all & character in the text ignoring encodings like &#41;, &nbsp; etc

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

My requirement is  given a string like this,

```
Edit the Expression    &1   Text to  & se&e matches &#41;. Roll &amp; over &nbsp;  ma&tches & or t
```

I need to select all '&' characters ignoring ones in the encoding. I have achieved selecting all encoding characters. Here is a [demo](http://regexr.com/3g4ru). Now I need to ignore them select other '&'.

Comment: What do you mean 'ignoring ones in the encoding'? Do you mean you want to ignore the *entities* like `&#41;` but match other ampersands? You could first convert all the entities to the characters they represent and then go back and search for ampersands, but that would. still match any that had been encoded as `&amp;` or `&#38;` or `&#x26;`.

Comment: You assume all textual entities are 4 characters long which is not the case.  Have you considered converting to text with the entities to rendered text then performing your match?

Comment: You can 'negate' your regex via negative lookahead: `&(?!#?(\d{2}|\w{4});)` - but first you should fix your regex to really match all 'encoding characters'.

Comment: What will you do with both types of `&`? Replace? Please provide an example output for your given input.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex may be considered as work in progress, e.g. to match `&#x26;` you also may write your current regex as `&(?:#x?)?(?:\d{2}|\w{4});`. To generalize it a bit, you may even change it to `/&(?:#x?)?\w{1,4};/`.

Your question is how to *negate* these entities, and match `&` in all other locations. It is easy to achieve a with capturing group and a bit of code.

```js
var s = "Edit the Expression    &   Text to  & see matches &#41;. Roll &amp; over &nbsp;  ma&tches & or the expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. Save Favorites & Share expressions with friends or the Community. Explore & your results with & Tools. A full & Reference & Help is ava&ilable in & the Library, or watch the video Tutorial. &amp; or &#38; or &#x26;";
var re = /(&(?:#x?)?\w{1,4};)|&/g;
var result = s.replace(re, function($0,$1) {return $1 ? $1 : "&amp;";});
console.log(result);
```

Here, the pattern is `/(&(?:#x?)?\w{1,4};)|&/g` - `(<YOUR_NEGATED_PATTERN>)|&`. Your pattern is captured into Group 1 and when a match is found, Group 1 value is checked: if Group 1 matched, the entity is put back into the resulting string. All other `&` are turned into `&amp;`.